# UITableViewCell conflicting height constraint

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I have a custom tableview cell where I'm letting auto layout manage the height for it.

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Inside the tableview cell I have a container subview:

`contentView.addSubview(calendarEventContainerView)`

All the content I'm adding goes in the `calendarEventContainerView` and I would like the subview to be a minimum of 120pts, but at the same time, I want it to be pinned to the contentView (so that it stretches the contentView out). The only time I can get it to display properly is when I get an error saying my code can't simulatenously satisfy the constraints. Here's my constraint code:

```
calendarEventContainerView.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge(.Top, withInset: CalendarEventLayout.verticalInset)
calendarEventContainerView.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge(.Leading, withInset: CalendarEventLayout.horizontalInset)
calendarEventContainerView.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge(.Trailing, withInset: CalendarEventLayout.horizontalInset)
calendarEventContainerView.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge(.Bottom)
calendarEventContainerView.autoSetDimension(.Height, toSize: 120, relation: NSLayoutRelation.Equal)
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reasons unbeknownst to be, setting the priority of the constraints down to 999 seems to resolve this issue for autosizing `UITableViewCell`s.